# How to solve the boundary value problem for $\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+xy=1 $

Tags: boundary-value-problem

How to solve the boundary value problem given below:

$ \frac{d^2 y}{dx^2}+xy=1  $ , with the conditions $ y(2)=5 $ and $y(9)=6 $ .

I know the problem is given Dirichlet Boundary condition but I could not find a suitable method to get the solution.

Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

This inhomogeneous ODE is related to the [Airy Differential](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) equation. It cannot be solved, as far as I know, by analytical methods using elementary functions.

Transform the ODE into the first-order form and try to solve it using the shooting method.

Another method would be to use perturbation theory to derive an approximate expression for the solution.

EDIT: As Dr. Sonnhard Graubner implied the solution looks terrible, which you can decide by your self by using [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27(t)%2Bt*y(t)%3D1).

Comment: If I try using Laplace's transform , would it be applicable ?  If not then how to get solution ?

Comment: Laplace Transform methods will also not help you solve this ODE. You can only solve it using numerical methods or by expressing the solution in terms of the $Ai(x)$ and $Bi(x)$ functions (see the link that I provided).

Comment: the symbolic solution by Mathematica Looks terrible

Comment: This will be easy if we use Linear shooting method using 2 initial value problem . But I am unable to compose it

Comment: Even using Airy functions, this is a big, big, big **monster**